# prove function is surjective /analysis proofs!!

Tags: general-topology, analysis, inverse

Suppose $f:(a,b)\longrightarrow\mathbb R$, differentiable, where $(a,b)\subseteq\mathbb R$ is an open interval. Assume that $f'(x)$ is not $=0$.

1. Show that there is an open interval $(c,d)\subseteq\mathbb R$ such that $f((a,b))=(c,d)$ (hint: $f$ is surjective on $(c,d)$).
2. Since $f$ bijectively maps $(a,b)$ into $(c,d)$ (it is injective and
   surjective), we may define an inverse function $g:(c, d)\rightarrow(a, b)$
   where $g(f(x)) = x$. Prove that $g'(f(x))= 1/f'(x)$ for all $x\in(a,b)$.

Comment: By "$f'(x)$ is not $=0$" you mean that $f'$ never vanish on $]a,b[$?

Comment: The French notation $]a,b[$ rather than $(a,b)$ is rarely seen in English.  A user named "Joe" tried change it to that notation, and I clicked on "improve" and not only changed it to round brackets, but made some other improvements.  "Joe" came back later I I clicked the "reject" button but was told his edit was approved.  The poster clearly preferred the more standard notation.  Are two users just approving everything by reflex without looking at it?

Comment: It isn't true, so Obviously you can't prove that

Answer (score 1):

1. Let $c=\inf \{\,f(x)\|a<x<b\,\}$,  $d=\sup \{\,f(x)\|a<x<b\,\}$,. The assumption that $f(x)=c$ for some $x\in(a,b)$ leads to $f'(x)=0$, similarly for $d$. The rest is IVT.
2. Apply $\frac d{dx}$ to both sides of $g(f(x))=x$.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest case of the [Inverse function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem).